# In AngularJS, how can I prevent a nested <button> from submitting the form that it's in?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form (done in AngularJS) for entering records into a movie database. Within the form I have a dropdown of actors which the user can select from to add to the movie record that they are in the middle of creating. When the user clicks the button next to the dropdown to add the actor to the movie, it submits the entire form. I could, of course, take the easy way and use a div instead a  but I feel that I shouldn't have to work around this like that. Is there a standard of way of dealing with this?

Comment: use `type="button"` on buttons to avoid submitting the form by them

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm.

Comment: Let me add it as an answer and if helped please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these situations, as buttons in default are `type="submit"`, Just set `type="button"` on all buttons that you do not want them to submit the form.
That would do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the click using `ng-click`.

In the Dom:

```
<button ng-click="handleClick()">I love Polka Dot Bow Ties.</button>
```

In the Controller:

```
$scope.handleClick= function handleClickFn($event) {
  $event.stopPropagation();

}
```

Stopping the propagation of the event, prevents the event from bubbling up to its parent elements and triggering your submit.

Comment: I tried this and I get an error because $event is undefined.

Comment: oh try without the () in `handleClick()`. Also can you show me an example of the function which is being called if that doesn't work.